# Use dql as expression in doctrine

Tags: php, database, doctrine

I want to build expressions that are or connected with the doctrine query builder.

Here is how i try it:

```
    private function filterAgeGroups(array $ageGroups) {
        foreach ($ageGroups as $ageGroup) {
            $criterias[] = "JSON_CONTAINS(g.ageGroupIds, $ageGroup) = 1";
        }
        return Criteria::expr()->orX(...$criterias);
    }
```

I get the following error: `No expression given to CompositeExpression`.

It works if i use `Criteria::expr()->contains` or any other method that is available on `exr()` instead of the string.

But i want to use the custom function `JSON_CONTAINS` that i added to doctrine.

I have another part of my code that looks like this:

```
$qb = $qb
                ->where('JSON_CONTAINS(g.ageGroupIds, :filterValue) = 1')
                ->setParameter('filterValue', (string) $filterValue);
```

There it is working.

So how can i make my first code example work?